# Corda keystore and truststore creation

Tags: kotlin, corda

I'm looking for detailed steps to generate corda certificates manually. I've followed all the steps as per mentioned here : https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V3.1/permissioning.html

But, I'm stuck at the step for assigning role to certificates. I'm getting below error when executed this command:

```sh
java -jar /home/centos/corda-workspace/network-bootstrapper-corda-3.1.jar /home/centos/corda-nodes/ /home/centos/corda-nodes/cordapps/corda-finance-3.2-corda.jar /home/centos/corda-nodes/cordapps/cordapp-example-0.1.jar
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Party certificate C=GB, L=London, O=PartyA does not have a well known or confidential identity role. Found: null
    at net.corda.core.identity.PartyAndCertificate.<init>(PartyAndCertificate.kt:25) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.obtainIdentity(AbstractNode.kt:812) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.generateAndSaveNodeInfo(AbstractNode.kt:178) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.generateAndSaveNodeInfo(Node.kt:353) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.startNode(NodeStartup.kt:142) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:115) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
```

Comment: `compatibilityZoneURL` refers to the network map more info can be found here: https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V3.1/network-map.html

Comment: Hi, how did u create the certificates ? can you please help me understand the process ? Is there a documentation for that ?

Comment: Hi, I've referred to this URL for creation of certificates: https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V3.2/permissioning.html

Answer (score 0):

See [CertificateManager.kt](https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/io/cordite/networkmap/service/CertificateManager.kt) in the open-source Network Map Service created by Cordite for an example of how to create certificates with the correct roles.

In turn, the Cordite Network Map Service delegates to `X509Utilities.createCertificate` defined [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V3/node-api/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/nodeapi/internal/crypto/X509Utilities.kt) in the main Corda repository.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use openssl to create the certificates? The certificate roles can be specified in openssl.conf:

```
oid_section     = new_oids

[ new_oids ] 
certificateRole = 1.3.6.1.4.1.50530.1.1

[ req ]
req_extensions  = cert_extensions

[ cert_extensions ]
certificateRole = ASN1:INTEGER:4
```

Replace '4' by the corresponding role number as specified in https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html#certificate-role-extension